# Multiple countdown timers error when a number reaches zero

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to learn countdown macros and I downloaded this file from Jerry Beaucaire's website. Thank you Jerry!
I tweaked it a little. Rather than counting a value from 0 to an infinite number, I made it to countdown a value to zero from a number that I type in column C. But an error occurs when a number reaches zero. How do I fix this error? And how do I make a button in column A switch back to "DOWN" when a number reaches zero?

```
Dim CountDown As Date

Sub Timer()
DisableTimer
CountDown = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.OnTime CountDown, "Reset"
End Sub

Sub Reset()
Dim Counter As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

If Evaluate("COUNT(B2:B5)") = 0 Then
    Call DisableTimer
Else
    For Each Counter In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B5")
        If Not IsEmpty(Counter) Then Counter = Counter - TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Next Counter
    Call Timer
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub DisableTimer()
On Error Resume Next

Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=CountDown, Procedure:="Reset", Schedule:=False

End Sub
```

[Source File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5qMBYTNyqH_OEY5MTRWWURxS28)

Comment: There is no such thing as negative time in excel. Once you reach zero you cannot subtract another second from the time value.

Comment: I want the countdown to stop when a number reaches zero and no error message popping up. I also want the switch to change back to OFF automatically when a number reaches zero. How do I do that?

Comment: Don't subtract a second from the cell's value if the cell's value is less than a second.

Comment: Could you give me some details? What code should I write and where should I put that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

> ```
> If Not IsEmpty(Counter) Then Counter = Counter - TimeValue("00:00:01")
> ```

With this:

```
If Counter > TimeValue("00:00:01") Then
  Counter = Counter - TimeValue("00:00:01")
Else
  Counter = ""
End If
```